# There is no row at position 2 C# Runtime Exception

Tags: c#, mysql, ado.net

I am retrieving data from db and displaying in Label. but the problem is that this cannot retrieve db tabel first row data. Its print Second row data. If i given the db first row c_code then it is given the Error "There is no row at position 2"  Kindly please solve my problem.
Thanks you

```
 private void Get_Purchasing_Amount()
        {
            try
            {
                string get_P_Amount = "";
                double var_P_Amount = 0;
                int var_C_Code = 0;
                string query = "select c_code as 'code' from `db_vegetable`.`tbl_payment_master`";
                DataTable dt_C_Code = method_Class.method_Class.FetchRecords(query);
                if (dt_C_Code.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i <= dt_C_Code.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        var_C_Code = Convert.ToInt32(dt_C_Code.Rows[i]["code"]);
                        if (var_C_Code.Equals(Convert.ToInt32(txt_Customer_Code.Text)))
                        {

                            if (check_All.Checked.Equals(true))
                            {
                                get_P_Amount = "SELECT IFNULL(`purchasing`,0) AS 'purchasing' FROM `db_vegetable`.`tbl_payment_master` WHERE `c_code` = " + txt_Customer_Code.Text + "";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                string dt_Query = "select `id` as 'id' from `db_vegetable`.`tbl_order_details`";
                                DataTable dt_C_O = method_Class.method_Class.FetchRecords(dt_Query);
                                if (dt_C_O.Rows.Count > 0)
                                    get_P_Amount = "SELECT IFNULL(SUM(t_price),0) as 'purchasing' FROM `db_vegetable`.`tbl_order_details` WHERE `c_code` = " + txt_Customer_Code.Text + " AND (`date` BETWEEN '" + txt_From_Date.Text + "' AND '" + txt_To_Date.Text + "')";
                                else
                                    lbl_Purchasing_Amount.Text = "0";
                            }
                            DataTable dt = method_Class.method_Class.FetchRecords(get_P_Amount);
                            var_P_Amount = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[0]["purchasing"]);
                            lbl_Purchasing_Amount.Text = var_P_Amount.ToString();

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            lbl_Purchasing_Amount.Text = "0";
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    lbl_Purchasing_Amount.Text = "0";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Q: Do you know which of your "select" queries it's "failing" on?  Q: Are you sure there are more than two rows for that particular query?  Q: Have you considered using an `order by` clause.  Remember- relational databases do *NOT* have any "intrinsic order".  By default, a SQL query is *UNORDERED*.

Comment: A:Select Query work properly, A:Yes i am sure in db tabel more then one row.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Now problem is solve the problem is that break key word.

```
private void Get_Purchasing_Amount()
            {
                try
                {
                    string get_P_Amount = "";
                    double var_P_Amount = 0;
                    //int var_C_Code = 0;
                    string query = "select c_code as 'code' from `db_vegetable`.`tbl_payment_master`";
                    DataTable dt_C_Code = method_Class.method_Class.FetchRecords(query);
                    if (dt_C_Code.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i <= dt_C_Code.Rows.Count; i++)//these line generate error please check this
                        {

                            //var_C_Code = Convert.ToInt32(dt_C_Code.Rows[i]["code"]);
                            if (Convert.ToInt32(dt_C_Code.Rows[i]["code"]).Equals(Convert.ToInt32(txt_Customer_Code.Text)))
                            {
                                if (check_All.Checked.Equals(true))
                                {
                                    get_P_Amount = "SELECT IFNULL(`purchasing`,0) AS 'purchasing' FROM `db_vegetable`.`tbl_payment_master` WHERE `c_code` = " + txt_Customer_Code.Text + "";
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    string dt_Query = "select `id` as 'id' from `db_vegetable`.`tbl_order_details`";
                                    DataTable dt_C_O = method_Class.method_Class.FetchRecords(dt_Query);
                                    if (dt_C_O.Rows.Count > 0)
                                        get_P_Amount = "SELECT IFNULL(SUM(t_price),0) as 'purchasing' FROM `db_vegetable`.`tbl_order_details` WHERE `c_code` = " + txt_Customer_Code.Text + " AND (`date` BETWEEN '" + txt_From_Date.Text + "' AND '" + txt_To_Date.Text + "')";
                                    else
                                        lbl_Purchasing_Amount.Text = "0";
                                }
                                DataTable dt = method_Class.method_Class.FetchRecords(get_P_Amount);
                                var_P_Amount = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[0]["purchasing"]);
                                lbl_Purchasing_Amount.Text = var_P_Amount.ToString();
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                lbl_Purchasing_Amount.Text = "0";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lbl_Purchasing_Amount.Text = "0";
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                }
            }
```

Comment: No.  1) You're probably better served with a "return" than a "break".  2) Perhaps you don't need a "for" loop at all if you had a different "WHERE" filter in your query.  But, MOST IMPORTANT: the original problem, `"There is no row at position 2"` was a problem with your index (your "for" loop).  You didn't *RESOLVE* the problem (by restructuring the loop).  You just put a band-aid on it :(

Answer (score 0):

1. I believe this is probably the issue:

   `for (int i = 0; i <= dt_C_Code.Rows.Count; ; i++) {...}`

   Please consider substituting `foreach (DataRow row in dt_C_Code.Rows) { ...}`
2. If it's important which row should logically come "first", then please consider using an `order by` clause in your SQL statement.

Comment: thanks for reply but foreach loop how to use in this if condition. Ex: if (var_C_Code.Equals(Convert.ToInt32(txt_Customer_Code.Text))) {....}

Comment: The problem with `for (int i...)` is that your loop counter might be off.  Using `foreach(row)` eliminates that risk.  Your assignment will then be `var_C_Code = Convert.ToInt32(row["code"]);`